# How to propagate metadata from a folder into a document?

Tags: folder, column-data

I have read that SharePoint 2010 will push metadata from a Folder into documents provided both share the same site column, i.e.:

Both my folder ("Test Folder Type") & document ("Test Document Type") share the "Country" column.

I have created an instance of each but can't seem to get the Country value to propagate into the document.

Any tips?

Answer (score 6):

You can set default values for columns on a per folder basis.  It won't match folder value but you can specify a default value.  Of course the user could change the value later.

Go to your document library and then view the library settings.  You will see a link called "Column default value settings."  Click and you will be able to set default values for columns based on what folder the document is located.  In the left column you navigate to you folder and then set the values in the main part of the screen.

Comment: So that's how I figured it would work, but I don't see the option to select the location. In that screen there is nowhere to navigate to a folder (just the root folder). Is there feature I need to have turned on?

Comment: The answer is correct, however it seems on my server it's not visible. I've accessed somebody else's environment and it works as advertised. :(

Comment: Scratch that, I was being stupid. Need to make sure the folder is approved, then it shows up in the page.

Comment: This also works on SharePoint online but not when you drag an existing document in a folder (modern UI).

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure you can do that with folders, but should consider using Document Sets because they do share metadata with subitems.

[About documents sets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff603637.aspx)

> Document Sets is a new feature in SharePoint Server 2010 that enables an organization to  manage a single deliverable, or work product, which can include multiple documents or files. A Document Set is a special kind of folder that combines unique Document Set attributes, the attributes and behavior of folders and documents, and provides a user interface (UI), metadata, and object model elements to help manage all aspects of the work product.

Comment: Thanks Toni, I've looked at document sets and they don't match my need for a few reasons:
- Once a document is placed in a document set you forever lose the ability to edit its properties independent of the document set (i.e. if I move the document out of the document set)
- Document Sets don't allow folders

Both limitations are in conflict with my client's requirements.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know is to create your own "event receiver," a software development task.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint.SE and thanks for the answer! While  this may theoretically answer the question, I would recommend including more detail in your answer.